# Using crop package with XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, paper-size

When using the `crop` package with XeLaTeX the cropping of the first page doesn’t work. While the following document compiles fine with PDFLaTeX the result with XeLaTeX is this:

[image: wring cropping]

As you can see the first page has crop marks but the size of the actual cropped paper. Is there a way to fix this?

```
% !TeX program = xelatex
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{paperwidth =10cm,paperheight=20cm}

\usepackage[a4,center,cam]{crop}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

---

Here are some information about my system and versions: I’m running **TeX Live 2015** (Intel 64bit; via MacTeX) on Mac **OS X 10.10.5**. I’m compiling this document with **`XeTeX 3.14159265-2.6-0.99992 (TeX Live 2015)`** and an up-to-date distribution, using the following files:

```
 *File List*
 scrbook.cls    2015/10/03 v3.19a KOMA-Script document class (book)
scrkbase.sty    2015/10/03 v3.19a KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-dependent basics and keyval usage)
 scrbase.sty    2015/10/03 v3.19a KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-independent basics and keyval usage)
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
scrlfile.sty    2015/10/03 v3.19a KOMA-Script package (loading files)
tocbasic.sty    2015/10/03 v3.19a KOMA-Script package (handling toc-files)
scrsize11pt.clo 2015/10/03 v3.19a KOMA-Script font size class option (11pt)
typearea.sty    2015/10/03 v3.19a KOMA-Script package (type area)
geometry.sty    2010/09/12 v5.6 Page Geometry
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
  ifvtex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.5 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
    crop.sty    2003/05/20 v1.9 crop marks (mf)
   color.sty    2014/10/28 v1.1a Standard LaTeX Color (DPC)
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
   xetex.def    2015/09/11 v4.06 LaTeX color/graphics driver for XeTeX (TeX Live/RRM/JK)
infwarerr.sty   2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
graphics.sty    2014/10/28 v1.0p Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
    crop.cfg
  lipsum.sty    2014/07/27 v1.3 150 paragraphs of Lorem Ipsum dummy text
 ***********
```

---

This is how my `crop.cfg` looks like (it’s the one shipped with TeX Live. I have made no user-config.

```
% crop.cfg for xetex - JK - 2007-01-19
% This attempts to persuade crop.sty to work with xetex
% Public domain

\@ifundefined{XeTeXversion}{}{
    %% Force crop.sty to use the "pdftex" driver (i.e., \pdfpagewidth, \pdfpageheight) with XeTeX
    \def\CROP@driver{pdftex}
}

\endinput

%% End of file `crop.cfg'.
```

I tried to play with the drivers in a new config, these are the results:

In all cases the crop marks are shown.

- `none`, `vtex`: all pages in the cropped size
- `pdftex`: all page in A4 except the first one (see screenshot above)
- `dvips`: only first page in A4 all others in cropped size

---

Using `geometry`’s `showcrop=true` is impossible since it breaks TikZ `current page` node coordinates.

Comment: Use `lualatex` instead of `xelatex`

Comment: A quick-and-dirty (but functioning) fix: Insert `\null\clearpage\pagenumbering{arabic}` immediately after `\begin{document}` -- and throw away the first page...

Comment: @Herbert: I Never used Lualatex, are there any other differences to care about. How about support for microtype.sty e.g.?

Comment: @Mico: Yep, that was my fix too, but I was hoping for a better solution ...

Comment: The `microtype` package works far better under LuaLaTeX than under XeLaTeX.

Comment: FYI: By using XeTeX and xdvipdfmx based on the latest TeX Live
sources, I obtain the same output as that by pdflatex.

Comment: @AkiraKakuto: Hm … with `xelatex -no-pdf  document` and `xdvipdfmx document.xdv` I get the same (wrong) result as with `xelatex document` …

Comment: @Tobi: I'm using newer XeTeX and xdvipdfmx
based on the latest sources in TeX Live SVN.
So my comment is only information.

Comment: @AkiraKakuto: Ah, ok. Thanks! What result do you get with `xelatex document` (i.e. compiling directly to PDF)?

Comment: @Tobi: I'm compiling directly to PDF: xelatex document.
Just now I have confirmed that even in the present TeX Live
binaries (win32), there is no problem for your example.
I don't know why your first page is wrong.
Some of used files:
`scrbook.cls    2015/10/03 v3.19a KOMA-Script document class`
`xetex.def    2015/09/11 v4.06 LaTeX color/graphics driver for XeTeX`

Comment: @AkiraKakuto: Could you please compare your file list with mine (added to the question) and what version number has your `xelatex`?

Comment: `XeTeX 3.14159265-2.6-0.99992 (TeX Live 2015/W32TeX)`.
All seems to be the same. Strange.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have the following crop.cfg. Try that.

```
% crop.cfg for xetex - JK - 2006-06-07
% This attempts to persuade crop.sty to work with xetex

\@ifundefined{XeTeXversion}{}{
    %% Use the "pdftex" driver (i.e., \pdfpagewidth, \pdfpageheight) with XeTeX
    \def\CROP@reqdriver{pdftex}

    %% make crop.sty believe this is valid
    \@ifundefined{pdfoutput}{
      \newcount\pdfoutput \pdfoutput=1
    }{}
}

\endinput
%% End of file `crop.cfg'.
```

Comment: I am as @Tobi using a Mac with TeXLive 2015 and can confirm that the `crop.cfg` from your answer fixes the issue. (with the `crop.cfg` of the OP, I get the same problem in the `pdf` as mentioned in the question).

Comment: Indeed your (older) config file works. Any ideas to whom I can report this? Unfortunately there’s no contact information in the manual of `crop` and the last update was 2003 …

Answer (score 9):

It is a problem with `scrbook`, with `book` the example works fine. In the end it boils down to the fact that (newer versions of) scrbook inserts a `\special` at `\begin{document}`. One can reproduce the problem with this code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[paperwidth =10cm,paperheight=20cm]{geometry}
\AtBeginDocument{\special {papersize=\the \paperwidth ,\the \paperheight }}
\usepackage[a4,center,cam]{crop}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%\makeatletter\let\scr@ifdvioutput\@gobble \show\@begindocumenthook

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

The code is inserted by scrbook with a `\scr@ifdvioutput` test, this explains why the problem disappears if one defines `\pdfoutput` and set it to 1. Imho the problem should be reported to the KOMA author.

### Edit

A work around is to add another `\special`:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[paperwidth =10cm,paperheight=20cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[a4,center,cam]{crop}
\AtBeginDocument{\special {papersize=\the \stockwidth ,\the \stockheight }}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for finding that out! I’ll contact Markus to report this.

Comment: @jfbu: I don't understand your remark. graphics loads xetex.def on my machine and not pdftex.def.

Comment: I posted the issue in the german KOMA-Script-Forum: http://www.komascript.de/node/1982

Comment: sorry, got confused by current confusing ``using `pdftex' graphics driver`` log message from `crop.sty`. My bad. Best would be for `crop.sty` to be updated rather than force it to act as if under `pdftex` and consequent log messages.

Comment: good catch and fix! (deleting my earlier comment where I had erred about `graphics`)

Comment: @Tobi: I saw the discussion on koma script. The main question is why koma uses a \special for xelatex, it is not needed as xetex uses `\pdfpagewidth` (and neither geometry nor graphics, nor hyperref seems to have this sideeffect).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: I don’t know, but you may like to join the conversation over there and ask Markus. Maybe it’s just because he only had PDFLaTeX in mind …

Answer (score 5):

In July [I posted this problem on the KOMA-Script Forum](http://www.komascript.de/node/1955) and was told that the new version of KOMA (3.18 and later) set `pagesize=auto` as a default. Using `pagesize=false` reverts to the old behaviour, which works correctly with the `crop`-package.

Comment: Thanks! I didn’t search the forum before posting my issue … mea culpa O:-)

Answer (score 0):

try adding

pdftex,
% or any other renderer

in the options of the package, e.g.:

\usepackage[pdftex,a4,center,cam]{crop}

It worked for me.